# AjaxControlToolkit HtmlEditorExtender Error: AjaxControlToolkit.pdb not loaded

Tags: ajax, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit, pdb-files, htmleditorextender

I want to use AjaxControlToolkit HtmlEditorExtender. I have AjaxControlToolkit.dll and everything but when I run the application on localhost, exception thrown

```
 `Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in AjaxControlToolkit.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in Web.dll`
```

and when I do not break exceptions I got an error which is 
            `AjaxControlToolkit.pdb not loaded`

Here is my code:

```
                    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" >
                    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextEditor" runat="server" Height="191px" OnTextChanged="TextEditor_TextChanged" Width="746px" Text="Hello <b>world!</b>"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextEditor"  DisplaySourceTab="True">
                            <Toolbar>
                            <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                            <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                            <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                            <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
                            <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
                            <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                            <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />


                        </Toolbar>
                    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

> TEMPORARY SOLUTION:
>
> I added an attr in `ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender` ->
>   `EnableSanitization="false"` then it just worked fine.But I think it
>   causes a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed the `AjaxControlToolkit` correctly. I suggest you to install the library through `Nuget`. Also check, if the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` is included. Maybe you also need the `HtmlAgilityPack` and `SanitizerProviders` library/dll.

Make sure, that the following block is in your `system.web` configuration section in the `web.config` file:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajayToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

If this is given, you can inplement the `AjaxControlToolkit` on your page.

Comment: thank for answering. I have `ajaxcontroltoolkit`. I used it on another pages. My `web.config` file is fine, just like above you specified. and I have `HtmlAgilityPack` and `SanitizerProvider` under the `ajaxControlToolkit`. Still I dont know why I got that error

Comment: When I remove `<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>` it works fine with `<ajaxToolkit:oolkitScriptManager>` .So it is about HtmlEditorExtender